# JAXB test hand crafted beans

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, xsd, jaxb

I've got a bigger pile of hand crafted JAXB annotated files and some hand crafted xsd files. I've also got a few example xml files which should create most JAXB beans and set most fields.

How can I test if all important (95%) attributes are set? I don't want to hand test every attribute of every bean.

Can I maybe also or as an alternative test if the hand crafted beans match up with the xsd files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this, which should provide you with some sort of automation in the end; but it all depends on how complicated your classes and XSD are.

I would start by using JAXB's [schemagen](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/schemagen.html) against the set of classes you already have. It may require additional annotations you may have to add to your current codebase. With that XSD in hand, you could, mostly manually, compare the two XSDs to see if they're similar. Things could get tricky if choices, all, abstractions, groups, etc. are used in your model XSD.

I would then use XSD tooling:

- to generate all possible XPaths from these two sets, for given root elements, to ensure that you've got same coverage.
- to automatically  generate XML samples using one of the XSDs, depending on which one is your gold copy, and then validate it using the other XSD - to spot inconsistencies, as well as to unmarshall the XML using your existing code.

Once unmarshalled, as Blaise described, marshall and compare (ideally use a schema aware XML compare, then XML aware, text compare most likely would be useless).

Answer (score 1):

You could unmarshal the control XML documents and then marshal them back to XML.  Then compare the two XML documents to ensure they contain the same content.  This would validate the round trip case.